# feign client - retrieving jwt token from a service and setting it automatically in feign client

Tags: spring, jwt, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I'm using feign client to call other services.
Service A need to contact Service B and has to be authenticated via authentication service.

If I wasn't using feign, I would just use resttemplate calling first the authentication service.. get the token, add it to the header of the msg I want to send to service B.

Is it possible to configure to feign an endpoint that from there he gets the token so it would be done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have prepeared JWT authroization and authentication in the authentication service, i can give my example like this:

First feign client using OpenFeign (the latest feign implementation of spring)

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

// Must give a url to NOT use load balancer (we have a gateway)
// Otherwise it will throw "did you forget load balancer?" error
@FeignClient(url = "http://localhost:<port>/", name = "UserClient")
public interface UserClient
{
    @PostMapping(path = "login", consumes = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody String user);
    
    @GetMapping(path = "hello")
    ResponseEntity<String> sayHello();
}
```

Then get the jwt token like this: (This code can be in some mvc project)

```
String username = someuser
String password = somepassword
// I wasn't able to create a json but the below data would work with spring security
String user = "{\"username\":\"" + username + "\",\"password\":\"" + password + "\"}";
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = userClient.login(user);
// your token could be like "<username> - <token>" kind of structure
String token = responseEntity.getBody();
```

Then make an authenticated request with openfeign, this code can be in mvc project or something

```
// If you put the token in session
String bearer = (String) req.getSession().getAttribute("Bearer");
UserClient helloClient = Feign.builder().client(new Client.Default((SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(), null)).contract(new SpringMvcContract()).requestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor()
{
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate template)
    {
        System.err.println("This is adding jwt header to resttemplate of the feign");
        template.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
    }
}).decoder(new Decoder()
{
    @Override
    public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException, DecodeException, FeignException
    {
        // If you have returned responseentity, feign client must be able to understand it
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response.body().toString(), HttpStatus.resolve(response.status()));
    }
}).target(UserClient.class, "http://localhost:4441/hello/");
// My responsebody is a simple string but it could be anything you want, as long as you have the decoder
String response = helloClient.sayHello().getBody();
```

Feign clients does not have the ability to dynamically set headers, especially from jwt tokens because those tokens are coming from either another request or in session. That is why i use builder to set a dynamic header. If you use BasicAuthRequestInterceptor, you can create a @Bean of BasicAuthRequestInterceptor and set a static username and password inside it.